# Getting a permission error when installing with bower

Tags: permissions, installation, bower

Everytime I try to install something with Bower I get a permission error like this:

```
Andreass-MacBook-Air:openMedia Andreas$ bower install jquery
/usr/local/lib/node_modules/bower/node_modules/configstore/index.js:56
            throw err;
                  ^
Error: EACCES, permission denied '/Users/Andreas/.config/configstore/bower-github.yml'
You don't have access to this file.

at Error (native)
at Object.fs.openSync (evalmachine.<anonymous>:500:18)
at Object.fs.readFileSync (evalmachine.<anonymous>:352:15)
at Object.create.all.get (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/bower/node_modules/configstore/index.js:34:29)
at Object.Configstore (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/bower/node_modules/configstore/index.js:27:44)
at readCachedConfig (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/bower/lib/config.js:22:23)
at defaultConfig (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/bower/lib/config.js:11:24)
at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/bower/lib/index.js:40:32)
at Module._compile (module.js:460:26)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:478:10)
Andreass-MacBook-Air:openMedia Andreas$
```

I imagine there might be an easy solution to this. But this is my first experience with Bower. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 53, accepted):

Tried with sudo ?

```
sudo bower install --allow-root
sudo bower install jquery
```

Another solution is to change the chown of your configstore folder

```
sudo chown -R Andreas:Andreas /Users/Andreas/.config/configstore/
bower init
bower install jquery
```

If there are more errors with eaccess, expand the chown to your whole home folder

Comment: First one works, but as I also had some errors with Bower in CodeKit using sudo didn't solve all my problems. However, changing the chown of configstore did! Thanks a bunch Aljoscha!

Comment: Second solution is the best one. 
chown -R <your_user_here>. ~/.config/configstore

Comment: You can also use the user alias: sudo chown -R $USER ~/.config, sudo chown -R $USER ~/.cache

Comment: sudo is always a bad idea if you want to properly manage the system, cause more permissions errors IMO

Answer (score 17):

Here is the fix, run below commands. it should work.

```
sudo chown -R $USER:$GROUP ~/.npm
sudo chown -R $USER:$GROUP ~/.config
```

Comment: @f-society excuse my ignorance, could you explain where to run those commands?  I'm using Command Prompt at the root of the project which indicates 'sudo' is not recognized as an internal or external command.

Comment: which operating system you are using? 
sudo is a Unix specific command, Windows does not support.

If you are trying to install bower on your Windows machine, I recommend using git windows bash, which gives you BASH emulation used to run Git from the command line, graphical user interface for using Git and Shell integration.

Answer (score 3):

Change the json bower configuration file .bowerrc  which looks like

```
{
    "directory": "www/lib"
}
```

to look like

```
{
    "directory": "www/lib",
    "allow_root": true
}
```

Answer (score -1):

you can just copy and paste this on your terminal

```
sudo chown -R $(whoami) $(npm config get prefix)/{lib/node_modules,bin,share}
```