# installing Bootstrap with Bower on mac says: Error: EACCES, permission denied

Tags: jquery, macos, twitter-bootstrap, bower

I am trying to install Bootstrap, jquery, and even fontawesome with Bower and keep getting: Error: EACCES, permission denied. Here is the message:

/usr/local/lib/node_modules/bower/node_modules/insight/node_modules/configstore/index.js:46
                throw err;

Error: EACCES, permission denied '/Users/joannak/.config/configstore/insight-bower.json'
You don't have access to this file.

Why is this happening and how can I fix it. I checked and have the latest version of Bower 1.6.5 on my mac.
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I had to correct my permissions to stop having this error.

I used chmod on my .config folder Recursively to correct my perimissions. Here are the commands:  
ls -al .config

chmod -R aog+wxr .config

Problem resolved.

Answer (score 0):

It's happening because you don't have permission to access that file.

If you `ls -l /Users/joannak/.config/configstore/insight-bower.json` you should see this - [permissions](http://www.rackspace.com/knowledge_center/article/checking-linux-file-permissions-with-ls).

Try running `sudo bower install --allow-root ...`.

Alternatively, you could `chown` or `chmod` the files, but that feels a little dirty.

*More Details:*

Try running:

`chmod u+rw /Users/joannak/.config/configstore/insight-bower.json`

If that doesn't work, because you're not the owner (which you can verify with `ls -l`), you need to make yourself the owner:

`chown YOURUSERNAME /Users/joannak/.config/configstore/insight-bower.json`

Might need to use `sudo` with the above commands.

**Edit:**

run `chown -R YOURUSERNAME: ~/.config`

Comment: I entered sudo bower install jquery --save and got: bower ESUDO         Cannot be run with sudo

Additional error details:
Since bower is a user command, there is no need to execute it with superuser permissions.
If you're having permission errors when using bower without sudo, please spend a few minutes learning more about how your system should work and make any necessary repairs.

Comment: Hmm, I'm not sure then. I found [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29865913/getting-a-permission-error-when-installing-with-bower), which might help, but the solution looks similar to mine.

Comment: `chown` changes the owner of the file, so if the problem is that you're not in the right group, you can use that to make you the owner of every file in some directory. `chmod` changes permissions, so you could give yourself read/write/execute permissions for any file. They have a recursive option so you can do it on a bunch of files at once. The link I posted has that solution.

Comment: I think that it is not recognizing me as the owner since it says: Error: EACCES, permission denied '/Users/joannak/.config/configstore/insight-bower.json' You don't have access to this file. I don't understand how to chmod from your message above, can you please explain what I should type. I don't want to assume and type the wrong thing. It's already a mess. Thanks

Comment: @JoannaK. sorry I'll update my answer. Changing permissions with `chmod` should be useful, but it won't let you if you're not the owner, so you have to first make yourself the owner with `chown`.

Comment: You actually got an error when running `chown` so it didn't affect anything. The usage looks correct... What if you removed the second `joannak` though I don't know why that would fix it.

Comment: No, "owner[:group]" is just some general information on the usage of the command - nothing to do with it not recognizing your username. As far as I know, the error is telling you that your syntax is incorrect. Let me think...

Comment: What if you ran it on the specific file (it should work on the directory, but just to simplify the command to help diagnose the issue). `sudo chown joannak:joannak ~/.config/configstore/insight-bower.json` (though there may be other files that it might need to use later...)

Comment: Try it without the second joannak, just `... joannak: ~/.config...`. If that doesn't work remove the `:`

Comment: I tried: bower install jquery but gave me:bower  EACCES EACCES: permission denied, open '/Users/joannak/.cache/bower/registry/bower.herokuapp.com/lookup/jquery_d223e' Also- Stack trace:
Error: EACCES: permission denied, open '/Users/joannak/.cache/bower/registry/bower.herokuapp.com/lookup/jquery_d223e'
    at Error (native) Also-Console trace:
Error
    at StandardRenderer.error (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/bower/lib/renderers/StandardRenderer.js:82:37)

Comment: not sure about the Console trace, but the other error you're getting is a permission denied error. You really do need to use chown with the `-R` option. Try the first command again, just without the group name (And with `-R`)

Comment: is the first part just your path? If I understand the output properly, it just means that it completed successfully. But don't run it for that file. `-R` is the recursive option - give it the `.config` directory. And then run the `bower` command

Comment: Run the command in my updated answer (at the end). I was saying that `-R` recursively navigates the file system tree and changes the owner for every file it encounters. You fixed the first error (that json file), but now there's another file that you don't have permission to use. So what you want to do is change ownership on every single file in `~/.config` so hopefully it stops complaining. This can be done by running the command I posted.

Comment: By the way, `chown` is not returning "Joannas-MBP:Documents joannak$", that's just what happens when you press Enter and go to a new line (you could verify that quickly). The command succeeds and so returns nothing (no error printout), but since you pressed Enter to run it, it goes to a new line and you see that "message"

Comment: OK, so I entered: chown -R joannak: ~/.config and got this: Joannas-MBP:Documents joannak$ can you please tell me how I can test this to see if there are any issues with installing packages with Bower. You mentioned above to give it the .config directory and then run the bower command. How do I proceed to install ex:jQuery to make sure I don't get anymore permissions denied with Bower?
Thanks again!

Comment: Again, `Joannas-MBP:Documents joannak$` just means that it succeeded. Why not just try running `sudo bower install ...` on whatever you want to see if it works

Comment: You could try `chmod -R u+rw ~/.config`

Comment: OK, I just did, no Error showed up, I tried installing and got Error: Stack trace:
Error: EACCES: permission denied, open '/Users/joannak/.cache/bower/registry/bower.herokuapp.com/lookup/bootstrap_ca4c5'
    at Error (native)....

Comment: I tried this sudo bower install --allow-root and got this result: 
bower                           ENOENT No bower.json present

Comment: I don't have much experience with that. Try looking the errors up [online](https://github.com/bower/bower/issues/1849).

Comment: Thanks for your help Pushkin, I appreciate your input! Have to figure out how to fix filesystem permissions that must be causing this. Thanks again!