# EACCES, permission denied when running bower

Tags: node.js, bower

For some reason my bower does not work when I run bower on the command line. It was working before, and all of a sudden it just stopped working

Everytime I type bower I keep getting this error message on the terminal

EACCES: permission denied, open '/Users/eldanshkolnikov/.config/configstore/bower-github.json'

I am not sure what this means??

I reinstalled bower and node.. and I am still getting this error message.. any help would be really appreciated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Getting a permission error when installing with bower](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29865913/getting-a-permission-error-when-installing-with-bower)

Answer (score -1):

I figured the issue.

I cd into the .config/ folder and changed the chown user from root to my username eldanshkolnikov

I was still having issues after... so I cleared tall the bower cache by going to

~/.cache/

and deleting all contents in the bower folder which did the trick